# Cucumber Scenario Outline not working with Junit 4.11 and Cucumber 1.2.5

Tags: java, cucumber, junit4, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am trying Scenario outline with example table in cucumber.
But an exception is thrown.
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to create scenario runner
I tried it with various versions of Junit and cucumber. Can anyone suggest the correct version of junit to use with cucumber so that this works.Other cucumber options are working fine exceot this. I have used junit 4.12 and cucumber 1.2.5 as well but of no use as far as Scenario Outline is concerned.

Comment: Please include also in question the Scenario Outline that you are trying to run and class which is being used to trigger the tests. I have used these versions together of JUnit and Cucumber with Scenario Outlines and never had an issue.

Comment: Scenario Outline: add two numbers
Given the numbers "<one>" and "<two>"
When adding those two
Then the result is "<three>"
Examples:
|one|two|three|
|3|4|7|

I have tried without quotes in placeholder as well...it throws an exception in ExamplesRunner class

Comment: Update your question with your feature file, or a snippet from it, so we can see it properly. Deciphering a comment will probably lead to something that is correct and since scenario outlines do work in, even in old version of Cucumber. My current guess is that your problem might be syntactical.

Comment: @user8867007 Please share also the code of the runner class.

Comment: I am using junit-4.12.jar just fine. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you figure out your problem with the help of the comments/answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on the reason of the exception. As the [code which throws the exception](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/a6113609b8e54ae535467675a7e4f4e3f1959def/junit/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/junit/FeatureRunner.java#L84) states that the cause is used to construct the `CucumberException`

```
} catch (InitializationError e) {
    throw new CucumberException("Failed to create scenario runner", e);
}
```

If for example your class `runner.Runner` would not be a `public class` the resulting exception message would look like

```
java.lang.Exception: The class runner.Runner is not public.
```

edit: This example was done with JUnit 4.12. The checks are different in JUnit 4.11 and 4.12. So this does not throw an exception in JUnit 4.11.

a JUnit 4.11 case could be a wrong `CucumberOption`.

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unknown option: --wrong-option
```

I believe there would be some more explanation in the exception message. Best would be you provide the code for your runner class.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many version of Junit and cucumber. after 2-3 hrs of struggle I was finally able to create the test runner. 
Use below dependencies. This combination worked for me

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these dependencies in your project, for me it is working fine.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
 <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```